# C++ operators ->

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-keyword

can someone please explain what -> operator does in C++?

Example below:

```
struct X{ int a[sz];}

void print(X* x){
for(int i =0; i<sz; i++){
    cout << x->a[i] << ' '; // -> is like dereference??
```

My guess is that it assigns index i in array a with the value of the object that x is pointed to.

Comment: You could look at a precedence table and search it by name. There are many, many explanations on the Internet and in any C++ book that dares call itself that, and it has been asked quite a few times on here.

Comment: There is no assignment going on. You should read an introductory C++ book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a member operator which is used to reference individual members of classes, structures, and unions. Unlike the '.' operator in Java, in C++ it is used only for Object pointers.

Comment: I see, I come from a Java background and have only begun C++ 3 days ago.

So the -> operator is used as a way to access a class's members in java? In java it would be like SomeClass.intMember .... 

In C++ it would be SomeClass->intMember ....

Comment: @MarcoSusilo, In C++ `.` is for objects, `->` is for pointers. It's just a syntax sugar. You could rewrite `ptr -> member` as `(*ptr).member`.

Answer (score 0):

a is a member element of struct X. -> operator is used to access members from a pointer to structure.
I'd recommend that you pick up a good book on C/C++ and read about structures.